# <input type="number" /> virtual keyboard glitch on Android 3.1 - PhoneGap solution?

Tags: android, html, cordova, browser, input

When I'm viewing a web page with a HTML5 form on my Android 3.1 device and tap on an input whose type="number", the virtual keyboard pops up which has the proceed button labelled "Next" - this is despite there being no other inputs (apart from the submit button) on the page. I enter a valid number, tap this "Next" button and nothing happens.

If I then tap somewhere else on the web page so the virtual keyboard disappears, then tap the same input again and the proceed button label magically changes to "Done"! So I then enter a valid number, tap this "Done" button and the keyboard disappears nicely out of view.

My question: How can I get his "Done" button to appear from the beginning? This problem occurs both when I view my app as a web app and when wrapped as a native/hybrid app with PhoneGap. Ultimately, my app will be a native/hybrid PhoneGap app so a solution on that level would be fine.